# Effectively COUNTing and SUMing on a large inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Please consider the following case (simplified for the sake of the question):

I have the following tables in the SQL Server 2012 database:

```
Parent_Table

Id  | Parent table fields
----+--------------------
1   | ...
2   | ...
3   | ...
...

Child_Table

Id  | ParentId | Child table fields
----+----------+-------------------
1   | 2        | ...
2   | 1        | ...
3   | 1        | ...
4   | 3        | ...
5   | 2        | ...
...

Big_Table

Id      | ChildId  | Value  | Status  | Other fields
--------+----------+--------|---------------------
1       | 12       | 672    | Closed  |
2       | 23       | 133    | Closed  |
3       | 7        | 2611   | Open    |
4       | 14       | 84     | Closed  |
...
1295769 | 23       | 458    | Closed  |
1295770 | 18       | 1046   | Open    |
1295771 | 7        | 8      | Open    |
```

The Child and Parent tables are relatively small (roughly 100 Parent entries and 5 Child entries per parent) and their entries are inserted or deleted only a few times a day.

The "Big Table", on the other hand, is growing fast (100 entries per second, for the sake of discussion), and the status of rows becomes Closed after a while (think of client sessions, which is the actually the case here).

I need to periodically (every few seconds) provide the number of Big_Table rows and the sum of the Big_Table.Value column **for a specified Parent.Id** - a different one every time.

I suspect that the straightforward implementation (using inner joins etc.) might be extremely inefficient, and better solution may include additional tables, a table of counters of some sort or I should just implement this in my service code (?!) and take care of persistence somehow.

What would be the "right" (efficiency-wise) way of implementing the above?  A solution which handles additional levels of parents/children would be the best one.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct indexes on the table, maybe partition it, then just use a join.  SQL can handle a large number of rows easily if you have your database designed correctly.

Comment: @cadrell0 - Obviously the indexes are a must (despite the extra cost upon insertions), but I'm not sure it's going to be enough in this case.

Comment: Did you consider an indexed view?

Comment: @Max - yes, I have, but I still think that it will require "too much" SQL resources while the engine is going to be very busy with other requests.

Comment: As long as you're using NOLOCK in the view definition, I wouldn't be too concerned with blocking. There's a good chance the SQL optimizer will realize what you're doing and help you out (cache results etc). I'd recommend trying this out and looking at execution plans and resource utilization. 
If the queries really are too expensive, add some caching logic to the business layer. But keep in mind that you'll have to deal with issues such as cache invalidation, keeping the cache in sync with the database etc.

Comment: @Max - It seems to me like your solution means creating a new view every time a child row is created, and deleting it when the row is deleted (or becomes inactive).  Is this a common practice with SQL Server views?
btw, are views updated together with the underlying tables (once a row is added to them, for example)?  This would mean that INSERT is slightly costier while SELECT from the view is very efficient.

Comment: No, you only have to create the view once. It won't require any kind of updates. If you add an index to the view, the index will get updated with every insert and therefore slightly slow down your insert performance.

Comment: @Max - I probably missed something. Did you mean adding a single view indexed on ChildId (this is actually Big_Table)?  Did you mean a single view which contains both ParentId and ChildId (not 3NF) and indexed on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we make the assumption that a ChildId always retains the same ParentId, then one option to consider is to add ParentId to Big_Table. If you are certain rows will only be added to these tables from application code you control (as opposed to, for example, someone with a database connection running INSERT statements themselves), you could keep a cache of the parent and child tables in memory and provide quick mapping of ChildId to ParentId when inserting into Big_Table. Then your sum/count query would be done entirely on Big_Table only. This denormalization of course will increase the size of Big_Table, but if that and application changes are tolerable this it is a viable option.

Furthermore, if ParentId is the primary way of accessing rows in Big_Table (or the one with the greatest performance concerns), then you could consider partitioning Big_Table on ParentId.

An entirely different approach would be to store the statistics you desire directly in  Parent_Table, and either use triggers on Big_Table to keep them updated or, if you control all the database interaction in application code, use application logic to update the statistics as part of a Big_Table insert. You could do this in-transaction to ensure consistency, or if you are tolerant of some error, it could be done as an asynchronous statistics update, so that inserts on Big_Table can happen quickly, while statistics get updated in the background.

As to handling additional levels of parents and children, you might need to choose between flexibility and efficiency. For instance, you might need to limit the depth of the tree you are willing to support in order to hard-code depth logic in order to improve performance.

Comment: Both assumptions on the 1st paragraph apply.  So do your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do a time test on the 2 below, if it is reasonable you can keep it simple.  I'll leave it to you to determine if the with(nolock) hint is appropriate for your situation (database settings, nature of the data.)  Since you know the parent id you don't need the Parent_Table involved.

Obviously there should be an index on Big_Table.ChildId and Child_Table.ParentId

```
select sum(Value)
from Big_Table with(nolock)
where ChildId in
(select Id
from Child_Table with(nolock)
where ParentId = @ParentId)

select sum(Value)
from Big_Table with(nolock)
inner join Child_Table with(nolock)
on  Big_Table.ChildId = Child_Table.Id
where Child_Table.ParentId = @ParentId
```